# removing an entire subdocument mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This should be really easy but I cant seem to get it working;

I just need to remove a sub-document that I had accidentally run and introduced undesirable info in the sub-document.

I tried - `db.test.remove({}, {dcoll10:{"$exists": true}, {multi: true});` but this didnt work.

Example of document and sub-doc (dcoll10) is given below;

```
{
 "_id": "SSS",
 "ts": { "$date": 1395927614611 },
  "dcoll10": [
  {
  "_id": "SSS",
  "type": "1813",
  "gro": "0.1",
  },
 {
  "_id": "SSS",
  "type": "1813",
  "gro": "0.1",
  }
 ],
 "assima" : [
   {......}
  ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the `$unset` operator which is documented here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/

Comment: I tried this, tentatively - it seems to work ;db.test.update({}, {"$unset":{"dcoll10":1}}, {multi:true})